# WCF Practises in Windows Phone

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have added a very basic WCF Service to my windows phone application. When hitting a button on the windows phone UI, I am calling `_service.AddTwoNumbersAsync(1, 2);`, which simply returns the answer in `int`.

I have a `AddTwoNumbersCompleted` event where I simply do `MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());`

This works perfectly fine and the correct answer is returned.

My question is - in terms of best practices, is this the most standard way of calling a method in the service? Am I not calling it properly? Do I need to do `OpenAsyn()` for anything? Is this a safe way of calling the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using it right now is the right way. You have a service client, calling the asynchronous method and binding to the callback event handler. There is really not much to it than this unless you will attempt to modify client configuration of use it synchronously.

Be aware that by calling an async method you are switching thread contexts - that should be your main concern, if anything.

Comment: Could you kindly explain the difference between ASYNC and SYNC. As far as I know, SYNC runs on the main threads and ASYNC runs on a different one. Is there anything more?